# How to handle multiple gestureRecognizer (same kind) in a screen Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I don't know how to work with multiple gestureRecognizers.

In this app, I have 1 label who will show a random number (1 to 3) and 3 labels linked to a different gestureRecognizers. The goal of this example is to write correct in the clicked label if the random number matches what the user touches.

I don't know if I have to do 3 different gestureRecognizers or only one and do the logic in the @objc func (but in this case I cannot reach the variable that I used in the viewdidload).

here is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var chance  = Int()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var random: UILabel!
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var number1: UILabel!
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var number2: UILabel!
    
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var number3: UILabel!
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        
        let chance = Int.random(in: 1..<3)
        print (chance)
        
        self.random.text = String(chance)
        
        
        let shuffle = Int.random(in: 1..<3)
        
        if shuffle == 3 {
            
            self.number1.text = "1"
            self.number2.text = "2"
            self.number3.text = "3"
            
        }
        
        else if shuffle == 2 {
            
            self.number1.text = "3"
            self.number2.text = "1"
            self.number3.text = "2"
            
        }
        
        else {
            
            self.number1.text = "2"
            self.number2.text = "3"
            self.number3.text = "1"
            
        }
        
        
        
        number1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        number2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        number3.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(verification1))
        let gestureRecognizer2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(verification2))
        let gestureRecognizer3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(verification3))
        
        number1.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        number2.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer2)
        number3.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer3)
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @objc func verification1() {
     
        print ("clicked")
        
     
    }
    
    @objc func verification2() {
      
        print ("clicked")
      
    }
    
    @objc func verification3() {
      
        print ("clicked")
      
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you choose not to use Buttons?

Comment: thx a very good question! Let me try with buttons!